# Ubuntu 16.04 changing the text I am typing when typed quickly and prefixed with "tri"

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, input

I noticed when typing string (very quickly) it shows something like the following:

`str]nig` or `sting` or `str]ng`

The same happens with anything prefixed by `tri` such as
triv: `t]iv`

This is happening anywhere I can type text.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe sounds like the effect you might get when two or more keys are depressed together in some keyboards.  Because of the way the key switches are wired (in a matrix), simultaneous presses may register as an entirely different key -- and if one of the simultaneous keys is released before the other, the correct key may also register.

I've seen the same thing happen in a number of different operating systems going back to my pre-DOS days in the mid-1980s -- in my experience it's most common when the computer is a little bogged down and so may not poll the keyboard or process the interrupt fast enough.

My suggestion would be to type a little slower -- you'll tend to make fewer of your own mistakes in that case, as well as reducing the likelihood of pressing two keys at once.  Failing that, you might check your system for excessive numbers of running processes that could result in your system (especially if older hardware) running slowly enough to cause problems.

Comment: I have a very new laptop that I am running on and this just started happening recently, next time I reboot before starting anything I'll try it again, but I don't think slowness is the issue, but I do think keys overlapping is a possibility, it's tough to just slow down my typing though.

Comment: When I was learning to type (in 1975) we used a metronome to set our rhythm.  I bet you can get a software versioh...